# Complement of Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

I'm currently reading this paper [Censored Exploration and the Dark Pool Problem](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/darkpools-final.pdf) and have difficulties in understanding the following simple equality:

Let $S$ be a positive integer random variable. Furthermore let $z_{i,s}$ denote the probability that $S$ is exactly $s$ given that $S$ is at least $s$. The authors then claim that $1-z_{i,s}$ is the probability of $S\geq s$ given that $S\geq s-1$.

In my understanding $z_{i,s}$ is a conditional probability, i.e. $z_{i,s}=\Pr(S=s|S\geq s)$. Then $1-z_{i,s}=1-\Pr(S=s|S\geq s)=\Pr(S>s|S \geq s)\neq \Pr(S\geq s|S\geq s-1)$. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: If you liked the answer then would you please hit the checkmark button. : )

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

$$z_{i,s}=P(S=s\mid S\ge s)=\frac{P(S=s)}{P(S\ge s)}=\frac{P(S=s)}{\sum_{i= s}^{\infty}P(S=i)}.$$

Then

$$P(S>s\mid S\ge s)=\frac{P(S>s)}{P(S\ge s)}=\frac{\sum_{i= s+1}^{\infty}P(S=i)}{\sum_{i= s}^{\infty}P(S=i)}=$$
$$=\frac{-P(S=s)+\sum_{i= s}^{\infty}P(S=i)}{\sum_{i= s}^{\infty}P(S=i)}=\frac{-P(S=s)}{\sum_{i= s}^{\infty}P(S=i)}+1=1-z_{i,s}.$$

Comment: Oh man, I really was blind. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!